# Ajuda com um formulario + php + javascript

Tags: php, javascript

Bom estou fazendo um sistema em que a pessoa escolhe a "Liga" + o "Modo" + quantidade de vitorias e então aparecer um campo para aparecer o email ( já consegui) e o valor ( Onde está o problema, não estou conseguindo resolver isso)

O problema está entre essas linhas :

```
if( ligas[lig_atu_val].valor == 1){
         var _valor = (divisao[div_atu_val] + ligas[lig_des_val].preco) * vitorias[num_vit_val];
      }else if(ligas[lig_atu_val].valor == 2 ){
         var _valor = (divisao[div_atu_val] + ligas[lig_des_val].preco) * vitorias[num_vit_val];

         for(var x = ligas[lig_atu_val].valor-1; x > vitorias[num_vit_val]; x--){
            if(x==1){y='bronze';};if(x==2){y='prata';}if(x==3){y='ouro';}if(x==4){y='platina';}
            _valor += 5*ligas[y].preco;
         }

         _valor += (5 - vitorias[num_vit_val]) * ligas[lig_des_val].preco;            
      }

      var valor_final = _valor.toFixed(2).replace('.',',');

      $("#_botao #_botao_email div").first().html("R$ "+valor_final);
      $("#_valortt").val(valor_final);

   }
});
```

Será q alguém poderia me ajudar a solucionar isso? pff.

Codigo completo:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Documento sem t&iacute;tulo</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0,maximum-scale=1.0,user-scalable=no" />

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>



</head>
<body>

<style>

#_opcoes_main{
   font-size: 0;
   display: block;
   width: 100%;
   text-align: center;
   color: #444;
}

._opcoes_div{
   display: inline-block;
   margin: 10px 0;
   vertical-align: top;
   font-size: 18px;
   width: calc(100% / 3.5);
   min-width: 300px;
}

._opcoes_div em{
   color: #2896c8;
   font-size: 1.2em;
   font-weight: bold;
}

._opcoes_div p{
   font-size: .8em;
   font-weight: bold;
   margin: 3px 0;
}

._opcoes_div select{
   border: 1px solid #ddd;
   padding: 10px 15px;
   margin-bottom: 10px;
   width: 200px;
   font-size: .8em;
}

._opcoes_div img{
   height: 120px;
   margin: 70px 0 35px;
}

#_botao_valor{
   font-size: 0;
   border: 2px solid #000;
   margin-top: 20px;
   display: inline-block;
   cursor: pointer;
   padding: 0;
   filter: grayscale(100%);
   transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
}

#_botao_valor:hover{
   filter: grayscale(0%);
}

#_botao_valor div{
   font-size: 18px;
   display: inline-block;
}

#_botao_valor div:nth-child(1){
   font-weight: bold;
   background: #eff2f4;
   padding: 12px;
   border-right: 1px solid #000;
}

#_botao_valor div:nth-child(2){
   font-weight: bold;
   background: green;
   padding: 12px 20px;
   color: #fff;
}

#_botao label{
   font-size: 16px;
}

#_botao label #_email{
   font-size: 18px;
   border: 1px solid #bbb;
   padding: 10px;
   margin: 3px 0 20px;
   width: 270px;
}
</style>
<div id="_opcoes_main">
   <form action="elos2.php" id="_form" onsubmit="return valEmail()" method="post">
      <input type="hidden" id="_valortt" name="_valortt" />
      <div class="_opcoes_div">
         <em>1.</em> <strong>Selecione a Liga e Divisão atual</strong>
         <br />
         <img id="img_ligatual" src="img_bronze.jpeg" />
         <br />
         <p>Liga</p>
         <select name="lig_atu" id="lig_atu">
            <option value="bronze">Bronze</option>
            <option value="prata">Prata</option>
            <option value="ouro">Ouro</option>
            <option value="platina">Platina</option>
            <option value="diamante">Diamante</option>
         </select>
         <br />
         <p>Divisão</p>
         <select name="div_atu" id="div_atu">
            <option value="v">V</option>
            <option value="iv">IV</option>
            <option value="iii">III</option>
            <option value="ii">II</option>
            <option value="i">I</option>
         </select>
      </div>
      <div class="_opcoes_div">
         <em>2.</em> <strong>Selecione a Fila desejada</strong>
         <br />
         <img src="img_bronze.jpeg" />
         <br />
         <p>Fila</p>
         <select name="_fila" id="_fila">
            <option value="solo/duo">Solo/Duo</option>
            <option value="flex">Flex</option>
         </select>
      </div>
      <div class="_opcoes_div">
         <em>3.</em><strong>Selecione a Quantidade de Vitórias que quer comprar</strong>
         <br />
         <img src="img_bronze.jpeg" />
         <br />
         <select name="num_vit" id="num_vit">
            <option value="3">3</option>
            <option value="4">4</option>
            <option value="5">5</option>
            <option value="6">6</option>
            <option value="7">7</option>
            <option value="8">8</option>
            <option value="9">9</option>
            <option value="10">10</option>
         </select>
      </div>
      <br clear="all" />
      <div id="_botao">
         <div id="_botao_email" style="display: none;">
            <label>
               <strong>E-mail</strong>
               <br />
               <input onkeyup="$('#_botao #_botao_email label strong').html('E-mail').css('color','#444')" required="required" id="_email" name="_email" type="email" placeholder="Insira seu e-mail" />
            </label>
            <br />
            <button type="submit" id="_botao_valor">
               <div>
                  R$ 0,00
               </div>
               <div>
                  ADQUIRIR
               </div>
            </button>
         </div>
      </div>
   </form>
</div>

<script>
   var ligas = {
   bronze: { valor: 1, preco: 3.00 },
   prata: { valor : 2, preco: 4.00 },
   ouro: { valor : 3, preco: 6.00 },
   platina: { valor : 4, preco: 8.00 },
   diamante: { valor : 5, preco: 18.00 }
}

var divisao = {
   i: 1,
   ii: 2,
   iii: 3,
   iv: 4,
   v: 5
}
var vitorias = ["3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"];

$("form#_form select").not("#_fila").on("change", function(e){

   var _mostra_btn = false;

   var lig_atu_val = $("#lig_atu").val();
   var div_atu_val = $("#div_atu").val();
   var num_vit_val = $("#num_vit").val();

   
if(e.target.id.match(/_atu/)){
      $("#img_ligatual").attr("src","img_"+lig_atu_val+".jpeg");
   }
   
   if(ligas[lig_atu_val].valor){
         _mostra_btn = true;
      }
   
   if(_mostra_btn){
      $("#_botao_email").show();
      
      if( ligas[lig_atu_val].valor == 1){
         var _valor = (divisao[div_atu_val] + ligas[lig_des_val].preco) * vitorias[num_vit_val];
      }else if(ligas[lig_atu_val].valor == 2 ){
         var _valor = (divisao[div_atu_val] + ligas[lig_des_val].preco) * vitorias[num_vit_val];
         
         for(var x = ligas[lig_atu_val].valor-1; x > vitorias[num_vit_val]; x--){
            if(x==1){y='bronze';};if(x==2){y='prata';}if(x==3){y='ouro';}if(x==4){y='platina';}
            _valor += 5*ligas[y].preco;
         }

         _valor += (5 - vitorias[num_vit_val]) * ligas[lig_des_val].preco;            
      }

      var valor_final = _valor.toFixed(2).replace('.',',');
      
      $("#_botao #_botao_email div").first().html("R$ "+valor_final);
      $("#_valortt").val(valor_final);
      
   }
});
   
   function valEmail(){
   if( !checkMail($("#_email").val().replace(/\s/g,'')) ){
      $('#_botao #_botao_email label strong').html('E-mail inválido!').css('color','#f30');
      return false;
   }
}

function checkMail(email) {
   invalidChars = " ~\'^\`\"*+=\\|][(){}$&!%/:,;ç";
   
   if(email==""){return false;}
   
   for (i=0; i<invalidChars.length; i++) {
      badChar = invalidChars.charAt(i);
      if (email.indexOf(badChar,0) > -1) {
         return false;
      }
   }
   
   lengthOfEmail = email.length;
   if ((email.charAt(lengthOfEmail - 1) == ".") || (email.charAt(lengthOfEmail - 2) == ".")) {
      return false;
   }
   
   Pos = email.indexOf("@",1);
   if (email.charAt(Pos + 1) == ".") {
      return false;
   }
   
   while ((Pos < lengthOfEmail) && ( Pos != -1)) {
      Pos = email.indexOf(".",Pos);
      if (email.charAt(Pos + 1) == ".") {
         return false;
      }
      if (Pos != -1) {
         Pos++;
      }
   }
   
   atPos = email.indexOf("@",1);
   if (atPos == -1) {
      return false;
   }
   
   if (email.indexOf("@",atPos+1) != -1) {
      return false;
   }
   
   periodPos = email.indexOf(".",atPos);
   if (periodPos == -1) {
      return false;
   }
   
   if (periodPos+3 > email.length) {
      return false;
   }
   return true;
}
   </script>

   </body>
</html>
```

Uma foto:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

como da pra ver não aparece o valor.

Comment: Acho que ao invés de `lig_des_val` que não está definido deveria  ser `lig_atu_val`

Comment: Também acho que essa linha ´}else if(ligas[lig_atu_val].valor == 2 ){` deveria ser `}else if(ligas[lig_atu_val].valor >= 2 ){`

Comment: vou testar aqui bro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se você quer multiplicar o valor do preço relacionado na opção "Liga" pela opção "Quantidade de Vitórias", teria que pegar o valor de um `select` e multiplicar pelo outro.

Antes de mais nada, o conteúdo desse `if( ligas[lig_atu_val].valor == 1){` me parece inválido. Tem muito cálculo para uma coisa simples, que é multiplicar um valor por outro. Tem uma variável `lig_des_val` que não existe também (!).

Outra coisa que notei é que o botão onde consta o valor está oculto com `style="display: none;"` e que ele só seria mostrado quando fosse escolhida alguma opção (`var _mostra_btn = false;`). Creio que isso não seja necessário, pois você já pode calcular o valor direto no carregamento da página baseado no valor inicial `3` do último `select`. Por isso não faz sentido também iniciar o botão escondido.

Tive que reescrever o código para fazer o cálculo e jogar no botão (principalmente excluir o citado `if` que não estava fazendo sentido). Tive também que colocar um `trigger` com `document.ready` para chamar a função `onchange` dos `select` `$("form#_form select")`.

> Notei também que o objeto `var divisao` não tem nenhuma função no
>   código. Se você não usa em outro lugar, pode apagar também.

**Veja funcionando:**

```js
var ligas = {
   bronze: { valor: 1, preco: 3.00 },
   prata: { valor : 2, preco: 4.00 },
   ouro: { valor : 3, preco: 6.00 },
   platina: { valor : 4, preco: 8.00 },
   diamante: { valor : 5, preco: 18.00 }
}

var divisao = {
   i: 1,
   ii: 2,
   iii: 3,
   iv: 4,
   v: 5
}

$(document).ready(function(){
   $("form#_form select").change();
});

$("#_fila").on("change", function(){
   $("#img_flex").attr("src","img_"+$(this).val().replace("/","")+".jpeg");
});

$("form#_form select").on("change", function(e){
   
   var _mostra_btn = true;

   var lig_atu_val = $("#lig_atu").val();
   var div_atu_val = $("#div_atu").val();
   var num_vit_val = $("#num_vit").val();

   if(e.target.id.match(/_atu/)){
      $("#img_ligatual").attr("src","img_"+lig_atu_val+".jpeg");
   }

   $("#_errmsg").hide();
   $("#_botao_email").show();
   
   _valor = ligas[lig_atu_val].preco*num_vit_val;

   var valor_final = _valor.toFixed(2).replace('.',',');
   
   $("#_botao #_botao_email div").first().html("R$ "+valor_final);
   $("#_valortt").val(valor_final);
      
});

function valEmail(){
   if( !checkMail($("#_email").val().replace(/\s/g,'')) ){
      $('#_botao #_botao_email label strong').html('E-mail inválido!').css('color','#f30');
      return false;
   }
   
   $("#_modal").show();
}

function checkMail(email) {
 invalidChars = " ~\'^\`\"*+=\\|][(){}$&!%/:,;ç";
 
 if(email==""){return false;}
 
 for (i=0; i<invalidChars.length; i++) {
  badChar = invalidChars.charAt(i);
  if (email.indexOf(badChar,0) > -1) {
   return false;
  }
 }
 
 lengthOfEmail = email.length;
 if ((email.charAt(lengthOfEmail - 1) == ".") || (email.charAt(lengthOfEmail - 2) == ".")) {
  return false;
 }
 
 Pos = email.indexOf("@",1);
 if (email.charAt(Pos + 1) == ".") {
  return false;
 }
 
 while ((Pos < lengthOfEmail) && ( Pos != -1)) {
  Pos = email.indexOf(".",Pos);
  if (email.charAt(Pos + 1) == ".") {
   return false;
  }
  if (Pos != -1) {
   Pos++;
  }
 }
 
 atPos = email.indexOf("@",1);
 if (atPos == -1) {
  return false;
 }
 
 if (email.indexOf("@",atPos+1) != -1) {
  return false;
 }
 
 periodPos = email.indexOf(".",atPos);
 if (periodPos == -1) {
  return false;
 }
 
 if (periodPos+3 > email.length) {
  return false;
 }
 return true;
}
```

```css
#_opcoes_main{
   font-size: 0;
   display: block;
   width: 100%;
   text-align: center;
   color: #444;
}

._opcoes_div{
   display: inline-block;
   margin: 10px 0;
   vertical-align: top;
   font-size: 18px;
   width: calc(100% / 3.5);
   min-width: 300px;
}

._opcoes_div em{
   color: #2896c8;
   font-size: 1.2em;
   font-weight: bold;
}

._opcoes_div p{
   font-size: .8em;
   font-weight: bold;
   margin: 3px 0;
}

._opcoes_div select{
   border: 1px solid #ddd;
   padding: 10px 15px;
   margin-bottom: 10px;
   width: 200px;
   font-size: .8em;
}

._opcoes_div img{
   height: 120px;
   margin: 70px 0 35px;
}

#_botao_valor{
   font-size: 0;
   border: 2px solid #000;
   margin-top: 20px;
   display: inline-block;
   cursor: pointer;
   padding: 0;
   filter: grayscale(100%);
   transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
}

#_botao_valor:hover{
   filter: grayscale(0%);
}

#_botao_valor div{
   font-size: 18px;
   display: inline-block;
}

#_botao_valor div:nth-child(1){
   font-weight: bold;
   background: #eff2f4;
   padding: 12px;
   border-right: 1px solid #000;
}

#_botao_valor div:nth-child(2){
   font-weight: bold;
   background: green;
   padding: 12px 20px;
   color: #fff;
}

#_botao label{
   font-size: 16px;
}

#_botao label #_email{
   font-size: 18px;
   border: 1px solid #bbb;
   padding: 10px;
   margin: 3px 0 20px;
   width: 270px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="_opcoes_main">
   <form action="elos2.php" id="_form" onsubmit="return valEmail()" method="post">
      <input type="hidden" id="_valortt" name="_valortt" />
      <div class="_opcoes_div">
         <em>1.</em> <strong>Selecione a Liga e Divisão atual</strong>
         <br />
         <img id="img_ligatual" src="img_bronze.jpeg" />
         <br />
         <p>Liga</p>
         <select name="lig_atu" id="lig_atu">
            <option value="bronze">Bronze</option>
            <option value="prata">Prata</option>
            <option value="ouro">Ouro</option>
            <option value="platina">Platina</option>
            <option value="diamante">Diamante</option>
         </select>
         <br />
         <p>Divisão</p>
         <select name="div_atu" id="div_atu">
            <option value="v">V</option>
            <option value="iv">IV</option>
            <option value="iii">III</option>
            <option value="ii">II</option>
            <option value="i">I</option>
         </select>
      </div>
      <div class="_opcoes_div">
         <em>2.</em> <strong>Selecione a Fila desejada</strong>
         <br />
         <img src="img_bronze.jpeg" />
         <br />
         <p>Fila</p>
         <select name="_fila" id="_fila">
            <option value="solo/duo">Solo/Duo</option>
            <option value="flex">Flex</option>
         </select>
      </div>
      <div class="_opcoes_div">
         <em>3.</em><strong>Selecione a Quantidade de Vitórias que quer comprar</strong>
         <br />
         <img src="img_bronze.jpeg" />
         <br />
         <select name="num_vit" id="num_vit">
            <option value="3">3</option>
            <option value="4">4</option>
            <option value="5">5</option>
            <option value="6">6</option>
            <option value="7">7</option>
            <option value="8">8</option>
            <option value="9">9</option>
            <option value="10">10</option>
         </select>
      </div>
      <br clear="all" />
      <div id="_botao">
         <div id="_botao_email">
            <label>
               <strong>E-mail</strong>
               <br />
               <input onkeyup="$('#_botao #_botao_email label strong').html('E-mail').css('color','#444')" required="required" id="_email" name="_email" type="email" placeholder="Insira seu e-mail" />
            </label>
            <br />
            <button type="submit" id="_botao_valor">
               <div>
                  R$ 0,00
               </div>
               <div>
                  ADQUIRIR
               </div>
            </button>
         </div>
      </div>
   </form>
</div>
```

Comment: pow cara muito obrigado mesmo consegui entender todos os meus erros agora, obrigado mesmo mano.

Comment: Eu queria dizer a `divisão`

Comment: No código dele essa linha `var vitorias = ["3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"];` dá pau no script

Comment: Veja minha resposta, nos cálculos entra a divisão

Comment: "Liga" + o "Modo" + quantidade de vitorias, pelo que entendi os 3 entram no cálculo, só que `Modo` deve ser o select `divisão`,

Comment: @LeoCaracciolo É, as vezes as perguntas confundem bastante. Ficou bom seu cálculo. Vai que ele queira calcular também selecionando a parte das divisões, pode ser útil.

Answer (score 1):

### Caso A - com select na quantidade de vitorias

```js
var ligas = {
   bronze: { valor: 1, preco: 3.00 },
   prata: { valor : 2, preco: 4.00 },
   ouro: { valor : 3, preco: 6.00 },
   platina: { valor : 4, preco: 8.00 },
   diamante: { valor : 5, preco: 18.00 }
}

var divisao = {
   i: 1,
   ii: 2,
   iii: 3,
   iv: 4,
   v: 5
}
//desnecessário    
//var vitorias = ["3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"];

$("form#_form select").not("#_fila").on("change", function(e){

   var _mostra_btn = false;

   var lig_atu_val = $("#lig_atu").val();
   var div_atu_val = $("#div_atu").val();
   var num_vit_val = $("#num_vit").val();

   if(e.target.id.match(/_atu/)){
      $("#img_ligatual").attr("src","img_"+lig_atu_val+".jpeg");
   }
   
   if(ligas[lig_atu_val].valor){
         _mostra_btn = true;
   }
   
   if(_mostra_btn){
      $("#_botao_email").show();
      
      /*
        aqui não há necessidade de um if else if já que as duas condições
        retornam o mesmo valor da variável _valor.
        Basta uma comparação para valores diferentes de 1 ( >=2 )
      */
      var _valor = (divisao[div_atu_val] + ligas[lig_atu_val].preco) * [num_vit_val];
  
       if(ligas[lig_atu_val].valor >= 2 ){
          /*
          Não está suficientemente claro a intenção deste loop for.
          Este loop for só funciona para diamante e quantidade de vitorias=3,
          portanto o propósito dele é duvidoso.
          Se não me engano, falta a condição para diamante
          */
        for(var x = ligas[lig_atu_val].valor-1; x > num_vit_val; x--){
          if(x==1){y='bronze'};
          if(x==2){y='prata'};
          if(x==3){y='ouro'};
          if(x==4){y='platina'};
          _valor += 5*ligas[y].preco;
        }

          _valor += (5 - [num_vit_val]) * ligas[lig_atu_val].preco;            
      }

       var valor_final = _valor.toFixed(2).replace('.',',');
  
       $("#_botao #_botao_email div").first().html("R$ "+valor_final);
       $("#_valortt").val(valor_final);
  
    }
});

/*  
function valEmail(){
   .............
   .............
}
*/
```

```css
#_opcoes_main{
   font-size: 0;
   display: block;
   width: 100%;
   text-align: center;
   color: #444;
}

._opcoes_div{
   display: inline-block;
   margin: 10px 0;
   vertical-align: top;
   font-size: 18px;
   width: calc(100% / 3.5);
   min-width: 300px;
}

._opcoes_div em{
   color: #2896c8;
   font-size: 1.2em;
   font-weight: bold;
}

._opcoes_div p{
   font-size: .8em;
   font-weight: bold;
   margin: 3px 0;
}

._opcoes_div select{
   border: 1px solid #ddd;
   padding: 10px 15px;
   margin-bottom: 10px;
   width: 200px;
   font-size: .8em;
}

._opcoes_div img{
   height: 120px;
   margin: 70px 0 35px;
}

#_botao_valor{
   font-size: 0;
   border: 2px solid #000;
   margin-top: 20px;
   display: inline-block;
   cursor: pointer;
   padding: 0;
   filter: grayscale(100%);
   transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
}

#_botao_valor:hover{
   filter: grayscale(0%);
}

#_botao_valor div{
   font-size: 18px;
   display: inline-block;
}

#_botao_valor div:nth-child(1){
   font-weight: bold;
   background: #eff2f4;
   padding: 12px;
   border-right: 1px solid #000;
}

#_botao_valor div:nth-child(2){
   font-weight: bold;
   background: green;
   padding: 12px 20px;
   color: #fff;
}

#_botao label{
   font-size: 16px;
}

#_botao label #_email{
   font-size: 18px;
   border: 1px solid #bbb;
   padding: 10px;
   margin: 3px 0 20px;
   width: 270px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="_opcoes_main">
   <form action="elos2.php" id="_form" onsubmit="return valEmail()" method="post">
      <input type="hidden" id="_valortt" name="_valortt" />
      <div class="_opcoes_div">
         <em>1.</em> <strong>Selecione a Liga e Divisão atual</strong>
         <br />
         <img id="img_ligatual" src="img_bronze.jpeg" />
         <br />
         <p>Liga</p>
         <select name="lig_atu" id="lig_atu">
            <option value="bronze">Bronze</option>
            <option value="prata">Prata</option>
            <option value="ouro">Ouro</option>
            <option value="platina">Platina</option>
            <option value="diamante">Diamante</option>
         </select>
         <br />
         <p>Divisão</p>
         <select name="div_atu" id="div_atu">
            <option value="v">V</option>
            <option value="iv">IV</option>
            <option value="iii">III</option>
            <option value="ii">II</option>
            <option value="i">I</option>
         </select>
      </div>
      <div class="_opcoes_div">
         <em>2.</em> <strong>Selecione a Fila desejada</strong>
         <br />
         <img src="img_bronze.jpeg" />
         <br />
         <p>Fila</p>
         <select name="_fila" id="_fila">
            <option value="solo/duo">Solo/Duo</option>
            <option value="flex">Flex</option>
         </select>
      </div>
      <div class="_opcoes_div">
         <em>3.</em><strong>Selecione a Quantidade de Vitórias que quer comprar</strong>
         <br />
         <img src="img_bronze.jpeg" />
         <br />
         <select name="num_vit" id="num_vit">
            <option value="3">3</option>
            <option value="4">4</option>
            <option value="5">5</option>
            <option value="6">6</option>
            <option value="7">7</option>
            <option value="8">8</option>
            <option value="9">9</option>
            <option value="10">10</option>
         </select>
      </div>
      <br clear="all" />
      <div id="_botao">
         <div id="_botao_email" style="display: none;">
            <label>
               <strong>E-mail</strong>
               <br />
               <input onkeyup="$('#_botao #_botao_email label strong').html('E-mail').css('color','#444')" required="required" id="_email" name="_email" type="email" placeholder="Insira seu e-mail" />
            </label>
            <br />
            <button type="submit" id="_botao_valor">
               <div>
                  R$ 0,00
               </div>
               <div>
                  ADQUIRIR
               </div>
            </button>
         </div>
      </div>
   </form>
</div>
```

> var `vitorias` desconsiderada.
>   Ao invés de `lig_des_val` que não está definido usei `lig_atu_val`

### Caso B - conforme pedido em comentário

**Para trocar esse form de quantidade de vitorias para uma barra de rolagem** - pode usar um input type range

```js
 var ligas = {
   bronze: { valor: 1, preco: 3.00 },
   prata: { valor : 2, preco: 4.00 },
   ouro: { valor : 3, preco: 6.00 },
   platina: { valor : 4, preco: 8.00 },
   diamante: { valor : 5, preco: 18.00 }
}

var divisao = {
   i: 1,
   ii: 2,
   iii: 3,
   iv: 4,
   v: 5
}
//var vitorias = ["3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"];

//Linha modificada em relação ao exemplo com select (caso A)
$("#_form, #quant").not("#_fila").on("change", function(e){

   var _mostra_btn = false;
   var lig_atu_val = $("#lig_atu").val();
   var div_atu_val = $("#div_atu").val();

    //Linha modificada em relação ao exemplo com select (caso A)
    //Retorno do value do input type range
    var num_vit_val = $("#quant").val();
    //valor mostrado no input de id = num_vit
    $('#num_vit').val(num_vit_val);
   
 if(e.target.id.match(/_atu/)){
      $("#img_ligatual").attr("src","img_"+lig_atu_val+".jpeg");
    }
   
   if(ligas[lig_atu_val].valor){
         _mostra_btn = true;
      }
   
   if(_mostra_btn){
      $("#_botao_email").show();
      
      var _valor = (divisao[div_atu_val] + ligas[lig_atu_val].preco) * [num_vit_val];
      
           if(ligas[lig_atu_val].valor >= 2 ){
             /*
              Não está suficientemente claro a intenção deste loop for.
              Este loop for só funcionaria para diamante e quantidade de vitorias=3,
              portanto o propósito dele é duvidoso e foi comentado.
              Se não me engano, falta a condição para diamante
              
              for(var x = ligas[lig_atu_val].valor-1; x > num_vit_val; x--){
                if(x==1){y='bronze'};
                if(x==2){y='prata'};
                if(x==3){y='ouro'};
                if(x==4){y='platina'};
                _valor += 5*ligas[y].preco;
              }
            */

           _valor += (5 - [num_vit_val]) * ligas[lig_atu_val].preco;            
          }

      var valor_final = _valor.toFixed(2).replace('.',',');
      
      $("#_botao #_botao_email div").first().html("R$ "+valor_final);
      $("#_valortt").val(valor_final);
      
   }
});
   
   /*  
   function valEmail(){
      .............
      .............
   }
   */
```

```css
#_opcoes_main{
   font-size: 0;
   display: block;
   width: 100%;
   text-align: center;
   color: #444;
}

._opcoes_div{
   display: inline-block;
   margin: 10px 0;
   vertical-align: top;
   font-size: 18px;
   width: calc(100% / 3.5);
   min-width: 300px;
}

._opcoes_div em{
   color: #2896c8;
   font-size: 1.2em;
   font-weight: bold;
}

._opcoes_div p{
   font-size: .8em;
   font-weight: bold;
   margin: 3px 0;
}

._opcoes_div select{
   border: 1px solid #ddd;
   padding: 10px 15px;
   margin-bottom: 10px;
   width: 200px;
   font-size: .8em;
}

._opcoes_div img{
   height: 120px;
   margin: 70px 0 35px;
}

#_botao_valor{
   font-size: 0;
   border: 2px solid #000;
   margin-top: 20px;
   display: inline-block;
   cursor: pointer;
   padding: 0;
   filter: grayscale(100%);
   transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
}

#_botao_valor:hover{
   filter: grayscale(0%);
}

#_botao_valor div{
   font-size: 18px;
   display: inline-block;
}

#_botao_valor div:nth-child(1){
   font-weight: bold;
   background: #eff2f4;
   padding: 12px;
   border-right: 1px solid #000;
}

#_botao_valor div:nth-child(2){
   font-weight: bold;
   background: green;
   padding: 12px 20px;
   color: #fff;
}

#_botao label{
   font-size: 16px;
}

#_botao label #_email{
   font-size: 18px;
   border: 1px solid #bbb;
   padding: 10px;
   margin: 3px 0 20px;
   width: 270px;
}

.vertical {
  margin-top: 50px;
   transform: rotate(270deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(270deg); /*do same for other browsers if required*/
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p align="right">Melhor visualizado clicando em pagina toda no canto superior direito
<font face="Times New Roman">&#8593;</font></p>


<div id="_opcoes_main">
   <form action="elos2.php" id="_form" onsubmit="return valEmail()" method="post">
      <input type="hidden" id="_valortt" name="_valortt" />
      <div class="_opcoes_div">
         <em>1.</em> <strong>Selecione a Liga e Divisão atual</strong>
         <br />
         <img id="img_ligatual" src="img_bronze.jpeg" />
         <br />
         <p>Liga</p>
         <select name="lig_atu" id="lig_atu">
            <option value="bronze">Bronze</option>
            <option value="prata">Prata</option>
            <option value="ouro">Ouro</option>
            <option value="platina">Platina</option>
            <option value="diamante">Diamante</option>
         </select>
         <br />
         <p>Divisão</p>
         <select name="div_atu" id="div_atu">
            <option value="v">V</option>
            <option value="iv">IV</option>
            <option value="iii">III</option>
            <option value="ii">II</option>
            <option value="i">I</option>
         </select>
      </div>
      <div class="_opcoes_div">
         <em>2.</em> <strong>Selecione a Fila desejada</strong>
         <br />
         <img src="img_bronze.jpeg" />
         <br />
         <p>Fila</p>
         <select name="_fila" id="_fila">
            <option value="solo/duo">Solo/Duo</option>
            <option value="flex">Flex</option>
         </select>
      </div>
      <div class="_opcoes_div">
         <em>3.</em><strong>Selecione a Quantidade de Vitórias que quer comprar</strong>
         <br />
         <img src="img_bronze.jpeg" />
         <br />

  <input class="vertical" id="quant" type="range" min="3" max="10" value="3" />
  <input id="num_vit" value="3" size="1" readonly />

      </div>
      <br clear="all" />
      <div id="_botao">
         <div id="_botao_email" style="display: none;">
            <label>
               <strong>E-mail</strong>
               <br />
               <input onkeyup="$('#_botao #_botao_email label strong').html('E-mail').css('color','#444')" required="required" id="_email" name="_email" type="email" placeholder="Insira seu e-mail" />
            </label>
            <br />
            <button type="submit" id="_botao_valor">
               <div>
                  R$ 0,00
               </div>
               <div>
                  ADQUIRIR
               </div>
            </button>
         </div>
      </div>
   </form>
</div>
```

> Para ficar na vertical foi usado uma classe css no input type range

```
.vertical {
   margin-top: 50px;
   transform: rotate(270deg);
   -moz-transform: rotate(270deg);
 }
```

Comment: obrigado mano !!

Comment: mano e como eu faria para trocar essa form de quantidadde de vitorias para uma barra de rolagem, q iria aumentando o numero de vitorias conforme a pessoa subisse a barra.